# How to get the last commit date of a file with ruby/grit?

Tags: ruby, git, jekyll, grit

I have a jekyll site, and I want to find the last commit date of a certain post using ruby/grit.

I know that I can do the following using git:

```
git log -1 --format="%cd" -- <file>
```

How can I do something equivalent using ruby/grit please?

Comment: To proceed, you should show us the code you have tried, and any errors you received when you ran it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
repo = Grit::Repo.new(...)
repo.log('master', path_of_the_file, max_count: 1)[0].date
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the File documentation for [mtime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-mtime):

> Returns the modification time for the named file as a Time object.

```
File.mtime("testfile")   #=> Tue Apr 08 12:58:04 CDT 2003
```

Ruby also supports [`ctime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-ctime), which is when the directory information for the file was changed. On Windows `ctime` is a little different behavior, because Windows supports creation times for files, unlike Linux and Mac OS.

Comment: I thought of that, but that wouldn't work for me. What I am trying to get is the date/time of the last commit on the file not the actual modification date.

Comment: It would be good if you clarified your question because you are saying commit time now, not modification time as is in the question.

Comment: First of all, sorry for the late response. You are completely right, I will edit the title right now. I also found out that `git log -1 --format="%cd" -- <file>` gives the date of the last commit on a file. What I was trying to do, is to do the same using Grit.